# Получить и передать массив значения через Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

Всем привет. Есть интересная задача.

Интернет магазин. В нем есть карточка товара. Переходим туда видим детальную информацию по товару. Ниже есть id комплектов к этому товару. Хочу реализовать добавление в корзину товара. Что есть: есть сама непосредственно функция по добавления корзину на стороне php, но нужно в эту функцию добавить массив из id комплектов. От сюда вопросы:

1) Как передать массив через ajax если я его получаю с помощью php.

2) как написать код передачи массива? раньше передавал только - наименование переменной:значение.

Все решается посредством Jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перед отправкой сформируйте массив с элементами, например так:

```
$('#id').click(function() {
   var test = [];
   $('.class').find(':input').each(function(i, input) {
   test.push(input.value());
   };
});
```

затем отправляйте эту переменную через AJAX:

```
 $('#id').click(function() {
 var test = [];

   $('.class').find(':input').each(function(i, input) {
   test.push(input.value());
   };

   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/test.php",
    data: {test: test},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log('error');
    }
    });
});
```

В Ваш php скрипт придет json-массив. С ним уже делайте, что хотите :) Если элементов в массиве мало, то можно писать их в строку c разделителем, передавать в виде одной переменной и на стороне php разбирать с помощью explode.

Comment: ок, а могли бы написать как должен выглядить Html. Ну точнее что бы взять значения с Inputa? он один должен или все значения через запятую?

Comment: не совсем понял, что вы хотите. Ну, например, так  <form class="inputs">< input type="text" value="1"/>< input type="text" value="2"/></form><button id="butt">Отправить</button>