# Передать определенные значения массива через ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, битрикс, post, php7

**Есть 2 кнопки по сабмиту на которые должны меняться статусы заявки по аяксу:**

```
 <form>

<button onclick="send_N()" class="btn btn-primary btn__sign" >Отправить замечания</button>
<button onclick="send_Y()" class="btn btn-primary btn__sign--else" >Замечаний нет</button>
</form>
```

**в обработчике :**

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php');
if ( $_POST['id'] > 0 ) {
    echo 'succes';
    CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValuesEx($arValues['EXTERNAL_ID'], false, array('STATUS' => 200)); // записываем в БД новый статус
```

}

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function send_Y() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/updstatus.php",
      //data: "name=John&location=Boston",
     
      success: function(data) {
        //alert("Изменение статуса 201 " + data);

      }

    });
    return false;
  }
```

как ***правильно*** передать конкретные значения массива ?

```
$arValues['EXTERNAL_ID']  // id текущей заявки
$arValues['STATUS']['ID'])  // Текущий статус (меняется)
```

Хватит ли этих данных чтобы обработчик сработал?

[предыдущий мой вопрос на эту тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/809788/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-setpropertyvaluesex)

[Похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628965/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-ajax)

Comment: уточните пож, в чем сейчас проблема? вы не знаете как передать эти даные ajax-ом на принимаемую страницу?

Comment: как правильно передать data , и как заставить выполниться код в обработчике

Answer (score 1):

Ну, раз вы уже пишете вызов функции инлайново, то можете сделать что-то типо

```
<form>
   <input name="deal_id" type="hidden" value="<?=$arValues['EXTERNAL_ID']?>">
   <input name="status" type="hidden" value="<?=$arValues['STATUS']['ID']?>">
   <button onclick="send_Y(this); return false;" class="btn btn-primary btn__sign--else" >Замечаний нет</button>
</form>
```

js код

```
function send_Y(e) {
let data = $(e).parents('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/updstatus.php",
    data,
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.result =='success'){
            console.log('lalal');
        }
    }
});
return false;
}
```

/updstatus.php

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['deal_id'])){
CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');
CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValuesEx($_REQUEST['deal_id'], false, array('STATUS' => $_REQUEST['status']));
$APPLICATION->RestartBuffer();
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>'success'));
die();
}
```